# Appium: cannot bind listener

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm trying to make my first Appium JAVA test.
This is my code:

```
    System.out.println("driver being created...");
    CommandLine command = new CommandLine("cmd");
    command.addArgument(" /c",false);
    command.addArgument("C:\\Appium\\node.exe",false);
    command.addArgument("C:\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\bin\\appium.js",false);
    command.addArgument("--address",false);
    command.addArgument("127.0.0.1",false);
    command.addArgument("--bootstrap-port",false);
    command.addArgument("4723",false);
    command.addArgument("--no-reset",false);
    command.addArgument("--log",false);
    command.addArgument("C:\\Users\\eliyahu.n\\appiumLogs.txt",false);
    DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
    executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    executor.setExitValue(1);
    executor.execute(command, resultHandler);



    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 0);
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Users\\eliyahu.n\\******.com.apk");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.ls.******");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.ls.******.activity.SplashActivity");

    Thread.sleep(8000);
    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Appium is trying to start but fails.
It starts appium, detects JAVA version, retrieves the device, indicates device ID, device API level after that is shuts down with the following log / errors:

```
[36minfo [39m: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\eliyahu.n\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 5DIBRCYL99999999 shell "pm list packages -3 com.ls.*****"  
[36minfo [39m: [debug] App is installed  
[36minfo [39m: [debug] Forwarding system:4723 to device:4724  
[36minfo [39m: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\eliyahu.n\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 5DIBRCYL99999999 forward tcp:4723 tcp:4724  
[36minfo [39m: [debug] Stopping logcat capture    
[36minfo [39m: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM  
[36minfo [39m: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...  
[33mwarn [39m: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone  
[36minfo [39m: [debug] Cleaning up android objects  
[36minfo [39m: [debug] Cleaning up appium session  
[36minfo [39m: [debug] Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Users\eliyahu.n\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 5DIBRCYL99999999 forward tcp:4723 tcp:4724"  
error: cannot bind listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:4723: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)  

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1184:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:484:11)
[36minfo [39m: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\\Users\\eliyahu.n\\sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -s 5DIBRCYL99999999 forward tcp:4723 tcp:4724\"\nerror: cannot bind listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:4723: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)\r\n)","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"cmd":"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\\Users\\eliyahu.n\\sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -s 5DIBRCYL99999999 forward tcp:4723 tcp:4724\"","origValue":"Command failed: C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\\Users\\eliyahu.n\\sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -s 5DIBRCYL99999999 forward tcp:4723 tcp:4724\"\nerror: cannot bind listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:4723: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
[36minfo [39m:  [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session  [39m [31m500 [39m [90m 23274.689 ms - 944 [39m  [90m [39m
[31merror [39m: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Users\eliyahu.n\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 5DIBRCYL99999999 forward tcp:4723 tcp:4724"
error: cannot bind listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:4723: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Users\eliyahu.n\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 5DIBRCYL99999999 forward tcp:4723 tcp:4724"
error: cannot bind listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:4723: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'QA-PC', ip: '172.20.1.87', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:161)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:64)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:36)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:114)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:132)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:92)
at MyFirstTest.setupTest(MyFirstTest.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed by changing the following code

```
command.addArgument("--bootstrap-port",false);  
command.addArgument("4723",false);
```

to

```
command.addArgument("--bootstrap-port",true);  
command.addArgument("4725",true);
```